# What is the exact danger of not waiting for peer's close_notify response?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

OpenSSL documentation says the following:
(Source: https://openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/SSL_shutdown.html)

> It is acceptable for an application to only send its shutdown alert and then close the underlying connection without waiting for the peer's response. This way resources can be saved, as the process can already terminate or serve another connection. **This should only be done when it is known that the other side will not send more data, otherwise there is a risk of a truncation attack.**

How would this attack work?

In the mentioned case, let's say the peer sends more data, but our side has already closed the underlying connection and will not read any more. I fail to see the damage the attacker can do.

Thanks!

Comment: try https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The danger is that data which the peer intended you to read does not arrive, and you don't know about that. It could be a transaction abort, for example.

Comment: @user207421 That is a good point in general. But in my case, my higher layer is closing the connection with no intention or possibility to process any data in either direction, and I am now considering if a fast close would be sufficient. I think that any missed data would be a bug in the higher layer.

It seems to me that the documentation was not precise. It is indeed a problem, but it is not a problem with fast close itself. Unless I'm missing something. Thank you!

Comment: This is the most recent discussion from the [TLS 1.3 RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-6.1).

Comment: I would be very wary of assuming that security solutions are not necessary in specific cases.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks! That one helped a lot! I learned that, even though my application layer would be perfectly correct, control messages, such as a new session ticket in TLS 1.3, could be lost if I cut the read side off. I think this is what user207421 was referring to, but I didn't understand it before.